# select owner who has all types of bikes

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, subquery

Below is picture of two tables, owners and vehicles.
I need to find out the owner who has all types of bikes.
[image]
Example: 
O_id 100,O_id 101,O_id 102 have bikes with V_id=1, but
O_id 103 has all types of bikes(V_id = 1 and V_id = 5)
How to write a query to get these details?
My Query:

```
select o.o_id from owner o,vehicles v where
o.v_id = v.v_id where v_type = 'bike'
```

this is showing all owners who have a bike,but not owners who have all bikes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by the `o_id`that you want to get.
Take only those groups having the same number (`count(v_id)`) of bikes that exist in total `(select count(*) from vehicles where v_type = 'bike')`

```
select o.o_id 
from owner o
join vehicles v on o.v_id = v.v_id
where v.v_type = 'bike'
group by o.o_id 
having count(distinct v.v_id) = (select count(*) from vehicles where v_type = 'bike')
```

Comment: can it be done using sub-queries?Honestly,i find this a little difficult to understand

Comment: That is using a subquery. I add an explanation to the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
with bykes as (
    select array_agg(v_id) as byke_ids
    from vehicle
    where lower(v_type) = 'byke'
), owner as (
    select o_id, array_agg(v_id) as v_ids
    from owner
    group by o_id
)
select o_id
from owner cross join bykes
where v_ids @> byke_ids
;
o_id 
------
103
```

The schema:

```
create table owner (
    o_id int,
    v_id int
);
create table vehicle (
    v_id int,
    v_type text
);
insert into owner (o_id, v_id) values
(100, 1),
(101, 1),
(102, 1),
(103, 1),
(100, 2),
(101, 3),
(103, 5);

insert into vehicle (v_id, v_type) values
(1, 'Byke'),
(2, 'Car'),
(3, 'Car'),
(4, 'Car'),
(5, 'byke');
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are two queries using subquery and join query:

schema:

```
drop table vehicle;
drop table owner;
create table vehicle(V_id int, V_type varchar(20));
create table owner(O_id int , V_id int);
insert into vehicle values(1,'Bike');
insert into vehicle values(2,'Car');
insert into vehicle values(3,'Car');
insert into vehicle values(4,'Car');
insert into vehicle values(5,'bike');
insert into owner values(100, 1);
insert into owner values(101, 1);
insert into owner values(102, 1);
insert into owner values(103, 1);
insert into owner values(100, 2);
insert into owner values(101, 3);
insert into owner values(103, 5);
```

subquery:

```
postgres=# select count(*) as bike_count, O_id  from owner where V_id in (
postgres(#    select V_id from vehicle where upper(V_type) = 'BIKE'
postgres(# )
postgres-# group by 2
postgres-# order by 1 desc
postgres-# ;
 bike_count | o_id
------------+------
      2 |  103
      1 |  101
      1 |  100
      1 |  102
(4 rows)
```

Join query:

```
postgres=# select count(*) as bike_count, O_id  from owner o join vehicle v using(v_id)
postgres-# where  upper(v.V_type) = 'BIKE'
postgres-# group by 2
postgres-# order by 1 desc
postgres-# ;
 bike_count | o_id
------------+------
      2 |  103
      1 |  100
      1 |  102
      1 |  101
(4 rows)
```

If you want just the owner, you can limit the queries to 1

Comment: What if none of the owners have all bikes?

Comment: if ask of your query is to get the owners having all the bikes, so if NONE of the owners have all(1 or more) the bikes then answer is NONE. right? or I am missing something.

Comment: right. But does your query return nothing then? I don't think so. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, it does. just run the delete "delete from owner where V_id in (1, 5);" and then run the select query. It returns None.

Comment: You are kidding right? Well you have my downvote. It does not work.